# Is there a way to rename a folder for a particular user after they logoff?

Tags: powershell, sccm

I need to rename a folder that is always in use when a user is logged on. If I have a user logoff is there a way for a script to then rename the folder when the user is logged off? I can use SCCM to deploy the script, I am just not sure how to get it to fire after the user logs off? TIA

```
Rename-Item -path "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\test" -newName "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\New"
```

Comment: You will need to do that using [Group Policy](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/using-group-policy-to-deploy-a-windows-powershell-logon-script/)

Comment: You can also run a script as a Scheduled Task triggered by logoff

Comment: If it needs to be run for the particular user will that still work even with them logged off?

Comment: It would work but it's kinda a race condition, the logoff would trigger the script, maybe the script would be fast enough maybe not and it would be terminated (probably fast enough because rename is fast but powershell could be slow. I would rather deploy it via sccm with the option "only run when no user is logged on" with system rights, then iterate through all user profiles and rename them all (except if you have roaming profiles then it wouldn't work)

Answer (score 0):

For this task you can use Group policy editor, and change logoff script. [microsoft_link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn789190(v%3Dws.11))